# DICOM Sequence delimitation item missed loading file (DCMTK)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compression, dicom, dcmtk

In one of my previous app I have used the DCMTK to create a compressed DICOM file. I use the DCMTK library only to manage the Pixel Data and make the compression. I mean that I have followed this wiki http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projec ... ressedData and after get the PixelData I have created a DICOM file with my function (Write, for File).

All works perfectly and I can open and see the compressed file without problem. Now I want to do the viceversa, so I want to import the compressed file that I have created, decode it and save again. I have used the simple example here (http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/mod_dcmjpeg.html) to decode but my program fail in the fileformat.loadfile function with this error:

`"Sequence Delimitation Item missing"` and on console I can read `"DcmSequenceOfItems: Reached the end of the stream before the end of sequence PixelData"`.

If use different files, compressed and uncompressed, not made by me the loadfile functions work... this mean, I think, that when I create the compressed file with the previous app something goes wrong even if I have checked the Tag and I can open the image with a Dicom Viewer software.

What means that error? How can I fix it? Maybe I must write the tag DcmSequenceOfItems before the creation of the compressed file?

Hope someone can help

Comment: The error sounds for me as if your length value of the pixel data tag ist wrong? Take a look at the DICOM image with an Hex-Editor and search for the PixelData tag and compare the length in the tag header with the actually bytes in this tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked the lenght and I thing that is OK because I make a comparision between a DICOM file that works with a DICOM file that give me that problem. The only difference is that in the file the works, exist a sub tag called `"Sequence Delimitation Item"`, (fffe, e0dd) that is under Pixel Data tag... How can I add this sub tag? Here: http://postimg.org/image/xtctn3krp/

Comment: Normally this tag must be created automatically if your DICOM framework is working correct. But I have never used this framework so I cant help you in that. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might as well be in how you are populating Pixel Data (in native format) when creating the uncompressed dataset. Uncompressed image should be encoded into Pixel Data Element itself and not encapsulated into 2nd Item Element and so on.  If you are missing the Sequence Delimitation Item, it is possible that you are not updating the element size for Pixel data Element with  appropriate padded uncompressed image data size.